# How do I delete my account on the beta?

Tags: support

I've removed any reputation-affecting posts, but I cannot delete my account.  This site has so very little to do with any manner of hack in regards to life that I want to remove any semblance of support for it, but don't seem to be able to.

Thank you for guiding me even when I'm sure you want to downvote me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) over  on the Stack Exchange Meta explains the ways to delete your account. Since you've interacted with the site, then you'll need to delete your account by using [this form in the help centre](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/contact).